# Javascript does not work at all. It doesn't echo a php variabla - only a blank page

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
$someVar = 1;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $someVar; ?>";
</script>
```

Javascript does not work at all. It doesn't echo a php variabla - only a blank page.

Comment: Your code works as expected. If you want to print something from JS, you'll need to use `console.log()` or `alert()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$someVar = 1;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $someVar; ?>";
    document.write(javaScriptVar);
</script>`enter code here`
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.